# generalise for-loop for specific lower triangular matrix

Tags: r, for-loop

I have an `list` of objects like

```
[a1 , a2, a3, a4, a5, b1, b2, b3, b4, c1, c2, c3, d1, d2, e1]
```

Have to print it like

```
a1
a2 b1
a3 b2 c1 
a4 b3 c2 d1
a5 b4 c3 d2 e1
```

using 2 for-loops?

Comment: Is it an `R` object?

Comment: It's a Plotobject

Comment: I have no idea what a "Plotobject" is. Voting to close since there is no reproducible example.

Answer (score 1):

If the initial data is a `vector` ('v1'), we can create a `matrix` ('m1') of blanks based on the frequency of letters and replace the lower triangular with the vector (`lower.tri`).

```
n<- max(table(sub("\\d+", "", v1)))
m1 <- matrix("", ncol=n, nrow=n)
m1[lower.tri(m1, diag=TRUE)] <- v1
m1
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
#[1,] "a1" ""   ""   ""   ""  
#[2,] "a2" "b1" ""   ""   ""  
#[3,] "a3" "b2" "c1" ""   ""  
#[4,] "a4" "b3" "c2" "d1" ""  
#[5,] "a5" "b4" "c3" "d2" "e1"
```

#### data

```
v1 <- c("a1", "a2", "a3", "a4", "a5", "b1", "b2", "b3", "b4", "c1", 
           "c2", "c3", "d1", "d2", "e1")
```

Comment: Thank you! Is this possible using for loops? If not, how should the data be rearranged such that it is possible?